# C strcpy and char

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I need to write a code that will to this: You enter names and first names and a grade. Only for the grade >= 10, you print the names and firstname of the student with a backward sort.
Exemple:

```
Bob
Dylan
12

Robert
Patt
9

Chris
Strozy
15

Josh
Sta
11
```

will give :

> Chris Strozy 15  Bob Dylan 12 Josh Sta 11.

My errors are on the strcpy lines :

> too few arguments to function 'strncpy'|
>   assing argument 1 of 'strncpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
 char tab_nom[N][M] ;
 char tab_prenom[N][M] ;
 float tab_notes[N];
 char tmp_n, tmp_p;
 int i,j,tmp;

for (i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
  printf("Saisissez le nom %d :", i+1);
  scanf("%s",tab_nom[i]);
  printf("Saisissez le prenom %d :", i+1);
  scanf("%s",tab_prenom[i]);
  printf("Saisissez la note %d :", i+1);
  scanf("%f",&tab_notes[i]);
  }

 for (i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
      for(j=0; j< N-1 ; j++)
      {
          if (tab_notes[j] < tab_notes[j+1])
          {
              tmp=tab_notes[j];
              tab_notes[j]=tab_notes[j+1];
              tab_notes[j+1]=tmp;

              strcpy(tmp_n,tab_nom[j]);
              strcpy(tab_nom[j],tab_nom[j+1]);
              strcpy(tab_nom[j+1],tmp_n);

              strcpy(tmp_p,tab_prenom[j]);
              strcpy(tab_prenom[j],tab_prenom[j+1]);
              strcpy(tab_prenom[j+1],tmp_p);

          }
      }
}
```

Comment: See [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

Comment: No, doing C for the first time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp_n` is a single `char`. `strcpy` takes `char*`

Comment: Ok Should i declare tmp_n as a tmp_n[20] ?

Comment: yes. because you are copying a string to another STRING not char. Try using it. It should work if you don't have other mistake.

Comment: It doesn't work, the code returns nothing but an error code "C0000005"

Comment: what other change did you make to your code? if you replaced char temp_n with char temp[SIZE] then this code is not supposed to give any error. probably you made another mistake to do this task

Comment: It's the only change. There isnt any compilation error, It return a huge number on the first grade

Comment: Can you give me your code please so that I can run and check it. Don't paste it here. Paste in paste.ubuntu.com and after pasting give me the link.

Comment: It working now, just a basic change. Thank you, I appreciate you time :)

Comment: You are most welcome. And you should know the best way to thank here is upvote :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
strncpy(tmp_n, tab_nom[j]);
/* ... */
strncpy(tmp_p,tab_prenom[j]);
```

You are trying to copy a string in a single character... Moreover `strncpy` has a third argument (`size`). Try `strcpy` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `strncpy` and not `strcpy`.

Definition of strncpy is as follows

```
char *strncpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2, size_t n);
```

so I think you would like to change your code as

```
strncpy(tmp_n,tab_nom[j],sizeof(tmp_n));
```

Else, you can use `strcpy(tmp_n, tab_nom[j]);` without any compilation error.

Comment: "Else, you can use strcpy(tmp_n, tab_nom[j]); without any compilation error." -> But with warnings and segmentation fault.

Comment: "Ok if i try with strcpy, should i declare tmp_n as a tmp_n[20] ?"

Comment: `strncpy(tmp_n,tab_nom[j],sizeof(tmp_n));` this is not how `strncpy` should be used.

Comment: It was a mistake, I need strcpy.

Comment: @Yanis: Yes, you will have to declare tmp_n as a char array or character pointer because of strcpy definition.

Comment: @mihirj It doesn't work, the code returns nothing but an error code "C0000005"